# CosmosDB Sdk has a problem with clock skew in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-cosmosdb

If my mobile device has wrong time (more or less 5 minutes than actual time), the cosmosDB sdk never works on any query. But it works if the time difference is less than 5 minutes from actual time. Now, the problem is, some of our customers can set time, say 10 minutes ahead of actual time. So we can't use cosmosDB Sdk anymore?

Comment: why are your customers messing with the clock on their devices?

Comment: You should have a service that communicates with Cosmos so that client clock times are irrelevant and also for security reasons.

Comment: @Jason, problem is I can't say customer to set their clock to auto. There are some mindset to set clock ahead so that they don't get late, but we can't do anything with that.

Comment: @Crowcoder, in SDK, I'm not getting any code, from where this sdk is taking system time, so that I can manipulate.

Comment: You have a connection string in your client app which is insecure. Regardless of system time issues, apps that users have access to should not communicate directly with cosmos

Comment: Means you are saying we should have server API which will be a bridge between app and cosmos? That is a good idea, but can we not resolve the problem what we are having now?

Comment: What is the response from cosmos when this happens? Status code, headers, response body,etc.?

Comment: "The authorization token is not valid at the current time. Please create another token and retry (token start time: ..." This is a common issue I can see at github

Comment: Right, tokens have a short window by design. It is not a TLS issue. [Maybe this will help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.requestoptions.resourcetokenexpiryseconds?view=azure-dotnet) but do you really expect it to be a problem for your users?

Comment: "The default value for this, should none be supplied is 1 hour (or 3,600 seconds).", but I'm facing issue after 5 minutes time difference. Its a clock skew setting done by cosmosdb sdk which is hardcoded I think. Any way to override that?

Comment: The SDK is not generating the error, there is no setting on the SDK. The SDK generates the payload and signature using the device time, and is sent to the Cosmos DB service, it is the service rejecting the signature due to the clock skew. The link for the Resource Token does not apply here, Resource Tokens are not auth signatures, those are different things.

Comment: Yes, but if I use http client, I can manipulate the date and post to cosmos. And that works.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behaviour and you'll find this with most secure systems.

SSL/TLS, for instance, which is what most web technologies use for secure transmission of data, relies heavily on clock synchronisation for certificate validation and revocation checks (amongst other things).

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72866/what-role-does-clock-synchronization-play-in-ssl-communcation

So it's pretty much the case that you're going to have to get your clocks synchronised or you're going to run into a lot of issues with this sort of thing.

The alternative, is to use unsecured systems. However, for the love of all that is holy, don't go down that route.

---

A potential workaround to all of this would be to containerise your solution and have an accurate clock within that container. That way your service knows the real time and what your customers have as their desktop clocks doesn't matter but it's really far from ideal.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But it's a xamarin form app which is running on each user's mobile. So, how can I manipulate? And if I use the REST service with http post/get etc, without using the sdk, will this problem be solved (if we can say it a problem though :) )

Comment: If you use a non-secured REST service, it should be fine, but I really, really would advise against it

Comment: I'm just using cosmosDb Sdk, nothing more.

Comment: Normally, using the SDK in the device itself would not be advised from the security perspective. Unless you are using resource tokens, you are technically shipping the service key into devices that could be decompiled and accessed, for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/architecture/solution-ideas/articles/gaming-using-cosmos-db

Comment: No, there is an API in between, which returning me the access keys. It's not hardcoded at mobile app.

Comment: If there's an API inbetween, then why not just make the clocks on your REST API accurate?